# How to fix Console output when Console.ReadKey receives an Escape key in C#?

Tags: c#, input, .net-core, console-application

I want to read user inputs from a C# console application targeting .NET Core 3.1.
In some situations, the user shall have the choice to cancel the input and the related operation by pressing the *Escape* key at any point of time when the user is prompted for input.

The following script works for empty strings (user just hit *Enter* and nothing else), and normal user input (user enters characters and confirms with *Enter*).

But there is a issue: When the user cancels the input (hits *Escape*), the first character of the following `Console.WriteLine` is suppressed, and `Console.Write` outputs nothing. Observations shows, that an line break must be outputted to restore `Console.WriteLine` and `Console.Write` expected behaviour.

Another issue directly related to this is that when I inject an additional line break, in the case of a normal input, I receive 2 line breaks, and in case of a canceled input, I receive 1 line break.

```cs
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        internal const ConsoleColor DefaultConsoleForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
        internal const ConsoleColor DefaultConsoleInputForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;

        internal static readonly Regex WhitespaceRegex = new Regex(@"\s{2,}", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);

        internal static readonly Encoding UTF8NoBomEncoding = new UTF8Encoding(encoderShouldEmitUTF8Identifier: false, throwOnInvalidBytes: false);

        private static void Main()
        {
            Console.InputEncoding = UTF8NoBomEncoding;
            Console.OutputEncoding = UTF8NoBomEncoding;
            Console.Title = @"ConsoleApp1";
            Console.TreatControlCAsInput = true;
            Console.Clear();
            Console.ResetColor();
            Console.ForegroundColor = DefaultConsoleForegroundColor;

            string firstName = ConsoleReadLine(message: @"Enter your first name: ", treatEmptyOrWhitespaceAsNull: true) ?? @"World";
            Console.WriteLine(@"Hello, {0}!", firstName);

            ConsoleReadKey(message: @"Press any key to exit...", hideInput: true, messageColor: DefaultConsoleInputForegroundColor);
        }

        internal static string ConsoleReadLine(string message = null, bool hideInput = false, bool treatEscapeAsCancel = true,
                                               bool trimInput = true, bool normalizeWhitespace = true,
                                               bool treatEmptyOrWhitespaceAsNull = false, bool addLineBreak = true,
                                               ConsoleColor messageColor = DefaultConsoleForegroundColor,
                                               ConsoleColor inputColor = DefaultConsoleInputForegroundColor)
        {
            string inputString;

            // Print optional message before the prompt (same line).
            Console.ForegroundColor = messageColor;
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(message))
                Console.Write(message);

            // Get input from user.
            Console.ForegroundColor = inputColor;
            StringBuilder inputBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            while (true)
            {
                ConsoleKeyInfo inputKey = Console.ReadKey(hideInput);
                if (inputKey.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
                {
                    inputString = inputBuilder.ToString();
                    break;
                }
                else if (treatEscapeAsCancel && inputKey.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
                {
                    inputString = null;
                    break;
                }
                else
                    inputBuilder.Append(inputKey.KeyChar);
            }

            // Optional input modifications.
            if (inputString != null)
            {
                if (trimInput)
                    inputString = inputString.Trim();
                if (normalizeWhitespace)
                    WhitespaceRegex.Replace(inputString, @" ");
                if (treatEmptyOrWhitespaceAsNull && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(inputString))
                    inputString = null;
            }

            // Reset foreground color.
            Console.ForegroundColor = DefaultConsoleForegroundColor;

            if (addLineBreak)
                Console.WriteLine();

            return inputString;
        }

        internal static ConsoleKeyInfo ConsoleReadKey(string message = null, bool hideInput = false, bool addLineBreak = true,
                                                      ConsoleColor messageColor = DefaultConsoleForegroundColor,
                                                      ConsoleColor inputColor = DefaultConsoleInputForegroundColor)
        {
            ConsoleKeyInfo key;

            // Print optional message before the prompt (same line).
            Console.ForegroundColor = messageColor;
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(message))
                Console.Write(message);

            // Get input from user.
            Console.ForegroundColor = inputColor;
            key = Console.ReadKey(hideInput);

            // Reset foreground color.
            Console.ForegroundColor = DefaultConsoleForegroundColor;

            if (addLineBreak)
                Console.WriteLine();

            return key;
        }
    }
}
```

Back a couple of ages ("the old days"), I had to double/triple read the keyboard input due to the control character was also submitted. However, there is nothing in the input buffer after the *Escape* key was registered.

**How to fix the input cancellation issues related to pressing the *Escape* key?**

---

Example 1 (**correct**)

```
Enter your first name: Test<Enter>
Hello, Test!
Press any key to exit...
```

Example 2 (**wrong**)

```
Enter your first name: Test<Escape>
ello, World!
Press any key to exit...
```

Example 3 (**correct**)

```
Enter your first name: <Enter>
Hello, World!
Press any key to exit...
```

Example 4 (**wrong**)

```
Enter your first name: <Escape>
ello, World!
Press any key to exit...
```

Comment: Normal behavior, you're printing the escape character to the console, so the following character will be a treated as a control character. You need to always hide Console.ReadKey and Console.Write the characters yourself (excluding the escape).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @jscarle, the solution is to not allow Console.ReadKey to print characters, but do it manually.

Here is the code, that fixes the `ConsoleReadLine` function.

```cs
while (true)
{
    ConsoleKeyInfo inputKey = Console.ReadKey(true);
    if (inputKey.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
    {
        inputString = inputBuilder.ToString();
        break;
    }
    else if (treatEscapeAsCancel && inputKey.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
    {
        inputString = null;
        break;
    }
    else
        inputBuilder.Append(inputKey.KeyChar);

    if (!hideInput)
        Console.Write(inputKey.KeyChar);
}
```