# Esc input cuts of Writeline

Tags: c#, input, console, console.writeline

So I tried to code an userinput with ConsoleKeyInfo. Its works. Than I tried to implement an cancellation when Esc is pressed. It works aswell but it cuts off some of my Writeline. When I try the same code with checking for example M it works just fine!

Is someone able to help?

My Code:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                string eingabeArtikelnummer, eingabePlatzalter;


                Console.Clear();
                Console.Write("Ein neuer Artikel wird angelegt:\n\nGeben Sie die Artikelnummer an: ");
                eingabePlatzalter = SteuerungUndEingabe();

                if (eingabePlatzalter == ConsoleKey.Escape.ToString()) { break; }
                else { eingabeArtikelnummer = eingabePlatzalter; }
            }
            WartenAufUser();
        }

        static string SteuerungUndEingabe()
        {
            ConsoleKey input;
            string userEingabe = null;
            do
            {
                input = Console.ReadKey().Key;

                if (input == ConsoleKey.Escape)
                {
                    userEingabe = input.ToString();
                    break;
                }

                userEingabe += input.ToString();

            } while (input != ConsoleKey.Enter);

            return (userEingabe);
        }

        static void WartenAufUser()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n\nBeliebige Taste druecken um ins Menue zu gelangen!");
            while (Console.ReadKey() == null) { };
        }
    }
}
```

This is the output in the Console:

[image]

This is how it should be:

[image]

Edit:

So I asked my Teacher how to fix this Problem. He had no idea why it occurs but he recommanded me to go around the Problem and change my Writeline to

```
Console.WriteLine("x\n----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n\nBeliebige Taste druecken um ins Menue zu gelangen!");
```

The "x\n" miraculously avoids the problem :D

Comment: There is no WriteLine in your code?

Comment: Due to my code being a bit bigger i just posted the parts i got problems with. I add it anyway!

Comment: We really need a [mcve].

Comment: @John okay :D give me a second

Comment: @John I hope this is a better example of mycode

Comment: That's much better :) I've managed to reproduce the problem with it, but I don't really understand it. It seems likely that there is some invisible character in the output that then fouls up the next write.

Comment: @John I tried to add some "newlines" but those were ignored and it the same outcome accured. 

Do you know another methode to produce the same result as mine should? Maybe a more efficient one? Than i can drop the problemsearching :D

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61973054/how-to-fix-console-output-when-console-readkey-receives-an-escape-key-in-c)