Console.ReadKey() consuming output of Console.WriteLine after when ESC was pressed
I have simple problem and I can't figure it out. I tried looking for other posts, but could not find direct answer to this problem.
Consider such code:
Console.WriteLine("Enter key");
var key = Console.ReadKey();

if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Escape pressed");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Escape Not Pressed");
}

When I pressed Escape, then I get output like this:
scape pressed

Notice first letter being cut out.
Why that happens and what would be the solution?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61973054/how-to-fix-console-output-when-console-readkey-receives-an-escape-key-in-c indicates it can be as simple as just using ReadKey(true) if you don't care about displaying the pressed key, or write it yourself otherwise
